# Get top 3 IDs with highest amount using window calculation in matillion etl

Tags: etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, matillion

I have a table that looks like this:

| id | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jesse | 192$ |
| 2 | sam | 123$ |
| 3 | steve | 345$ |
| 4 | josh | 234$ |
| 5 | hamish | 452$ |
| 6 | john | 211$ |
| 7 | watson | 111$ |
| 8 | amir | 143$ |
| 9 | riaz | 311$ |
| 10 | panag | 139$ |

Now, I want the id's of the top 3 people with the highest amount. I searched some around like window functions,aggregate component but I couldn't really find what I need.

I want the result to look like:

| id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 452$ |
| 3 | 345$ |
| 9 | 311$ |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the rank component, order by amount, window function = row number.
Then feed that into a filter component, and select row number <=3

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply run a SQL command using a Matillion Database Query Component - something like the SELECT in the following example?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE stacko_q 
AS
    SELECT 1 as id, 'jesse' as nm, 192 as amount UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as id, 'sam' as nm, 123 as amount UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 as id, 'steve' as nm, 345 as amount UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 as id, 'josh' as nm, 234 as amount UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 as id, 'hamish' as nm, 452 as amount UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 as id, 'john' as nm, 211 as amount UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 as id, 'watson' as nm, 111 as amount UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 as id, 'amir' as nm, 143 as amount UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 as id, 'riaz' as nm, 311 as amount UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 as id, 'panag' as nm, 139 as amount;

SELECT id, amount
FROM (
  SELECT  id, 
          amount, 
          rank() OVER (order by amount desc) my_rank
  FROM stacko_q)
WHERE my_rank <= 3;

--  results - 3 rows
--  ID  AMOUNT
--  5   452
--  3   345
--  9   311
```

Comment: I want to do it in transformation job and also my data contains 5000 records. It is not possible to write sql code for 5000 records. So is there any other way that u could enlighten me with?